# Library /data/data/../files/../lib/libMAPSJNI.so not found

Tags: here-api

I followed this [tutorial](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android/topics/app-simple-eclipse.html) from the website but I still get "Library /data/data/../files/../lib/libMAPSJNI.so not found" when I try to run the app. I am using eclipse and trying to run the app using the emulator with a device with an Intel Atom (x86) CPU with Android 4.4.2. In my libs folder I do have a file called libMAPSJNI.so. [image: libs folder]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, we do not support x86 emulators or devices. Please select an arm emulation image. However please note the emulator's graphical emulation is not perfect and may not work.

Comment: Is there an alternative to the android emulator?

Comment: Please purchase an android phone or tablet ?