# Is HERE SDK compatible with android api 21 >?

Tags: android, architecture, sdk, implementation, here-api

I try to implement the "[HERE SDK for Android](https://developer.here.com/develop/mobile-sdks)".

I did everything ask on the tutorial, plus trying to clone some github project using the HERE SDK. But I always have an error with "libMAPSJNI.so not found" when trying to launch some MapFragment.

I read [on another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711805/library-data-data-files-lib-libmapsjni-so-not-found) that it could come from the type of CPU architecture (arm, x86), Is That True? This post was asking about the same error, but launched in an Android emulator, so the best solution came from an HERE dev was to use an actual real phone..

Is this libraries not compatible with api ( >= android 21) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HERE SDK for Android supports Android 21 and higher.

However, you can't run your app on an emulator or a real device with x86 CPU, because currently, SDK doesn't support it.

Proper setup description https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/app-simple-android-studio.html

You can also download a basic example https://tcs.ext.here.com/sdk_examples/BasicMapSolutionGradle.zip and just put SDK in it as it's described in readme.

Comment: I do follow the proper setup propose by here to get this result.
When i try the "basic example" you are proposing : 
- On the emulator i got : "INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS", so you were right about that.
- On my real device (nexus 4, api 22), this app don't succeed to load the MapFragment with "UNKNOW" for error, is this relative to architecture too ?
I can use their app (HereWeGo) on my phone, so it has to be possible somehow.

Comment: Then add additional logging to get more precise error:
mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(Error error) {
                if (error.equals(Error.NONE)) {
                    // doSomething();
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, error.getDetails());
                    Log.d(TAG, error.getStackTrace());
                }
            }
        });

Comment: That's exactly what i did. And this the object Error error, who return error.getDetails() =>  UNKNOW. So i have no clue of what is wrong and why. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ArtemNikitin Not sure if it was at the time of writing the answer, but according to the documentation, minimum SDK is 15. Limitation to ARM devices still exist though.

Comment: @bajicdusko If you mean my phrase "HERE SDK for Android supports Android 21 and higher", then it was a response to a question about supporting specifically Android 21 version. In general, SDK supports Android from 15 as you mentioned. SDK currently still doesn't work on emulators and x86 devices with Android support. There was no change regarding that since my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a real phone? I dont think that using emulator is going to work with HERESDK.

Comment: Yes i do, its an nexus 4 api 22